# Handling magnet links with python selenium & firefox

Tags: python, firefox, selenium

As since I can't find any usefull information about this I decided to just put it out here.

I'm trying to automate downloading torrents by using python selenium & firefox. Everything works fine up until the point the magnet link is "opened", once that happens the script simply freezes.

My best guess is the magnet link doesn't really "load" like http links but I don't know how to get around this.

```
def lookup_and_download(query):
    #Focus Search box
    elem = browser.find_element_by_name('q')

    #Send Search Query
    elem.send_keys(query[0] + Keys.RETURN)

    #Select correct download link & start download
    element = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
        ".//*[contains(@title,query[1]) 
        and contains(@title,'eztv')]/../../*[@title=
        'Download this torrent using magnet']")
    url = element.get_attribute("href")
    browser.get(url)
```

I want to call this function multiple times of course but it just freezes right at the `browser.get(url)` line. The one download does work however.

Comment: browser.get('http://thepiratebay.se/recent')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently refreshing the page solves the problem.